# C++ - how to reinitialize object repeatedly?

Tags: c++, initialization, noncopyable

I'm trying to implement this logic in C++:

```
Object obj(args);
while (obj.isOK()) {
    obj = obj.next();
}
```

But I can't use this exact code because `Object` inherits `boost::noncopyable` so it has no assignment operator. I can add methods and constructors to `Object`, (but not make it copyable), however I would prefer not to. Other questions have manual destruction and placement new as a solution, which I could do if I create a new constructor for `Object`, but again, preferably I wouldn't need the new constructor, and that seems like a pretty nasty solution anyway. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: could you give the code for `Object' i mean the definiton

Comment: If Object is trivially copyable and destructable, you could probably memcpy it around.

Comment: @JamesRoot We should assume the class has been made non-copyable for a reason.

Comment: @drew If it's truly being constructed like `Object obj(args);` wouldn't that mean a user-defined constructor and therefore not a POD?

Comment: Yep, I've removed that comment. I thought POD encompassed more types than it actually does. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `Object::next` mutate the `Object` in place. Since `Object` is not copyable, this seems like the only sensible thing for `Object::next` to do anyway.

Answer (score -1):

What does `Object::next` return? 
If it returns a fresh `Object` you could add a move-assignment operator to `Object`:

```
Object& operator=(Object&& obj)
{
    //move its iternal state to this and then
    return *this;
}
```

So no data duplication takes place and nothing is actually copied.